# Connect and interact with Bluetooth LE devices on OSX

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm hoping to find a Python interface for working with Bluetooth LE on OSX. I've found [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy), but it uses `bluez` which seems to be designed specifically for Linux. As far as I know OSX has its own Bluetooth stack so `bluez` is no good there.

I've also found Adafruit's [BluefruitLE](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE) which seems to support OSX.

What is the canonical approach for working with BLE devices on OSX in Python? Which library is recommended?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X Bluetooth programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956563/os-x-bluetooth-programming)

Comment: alas. i'm playing with Adafruit_Python_BluefruitLE right now. its not playing nice immediately with Python 3 unfortunately, though I suspect the issues are pretty surface level

Comment: I have used [this](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) recently to develop on mac but was eventually deployed on Linux. Found it usefull for low energy devices.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS 10.12.X I'd recommend [pybluez](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez). I've had some issues in the past with installation on different hosts due to the [scheme argument](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/setup.py#L100) in setup.py, but commenting out that line if it fails tends to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[Bleak](https://pypi.org/project/bleak/) supports Windows/MacOS/Linux all in one neat tidy package.